# What is the proper way to create an apache-style log file using Erlang?

Tags: erlang, log-files

I think there is a specific module for this but can no longer figure out where I saw it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're interested in [disk_log](http://erlang.org/doc/man/disk_log.html) or [error_logger](http://erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html)?